# Spring Security Configuration and web.xml mapping

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee, spring-security

I am new to Spring Security and trying to figure out the exact flow of Spring-Security module,

Please suggest the right flow.

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
    <display-name>OnlineTestProject</display-name>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>
            org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy
        </filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/security/applicationContext-security.xml
            /WEB-INF/db/applicationContext.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>
            org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
        </listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>jsp/index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

applicationContext-security.xml

```
<http use-expressions="true">
    <form-login login-page="/jsp/login.jsp" default-target-url="/jsp/index.jsp"
        authentication-failure-url="/jsp/login.jsp?login_error=1"
        always-use-default-target="true" />

    <intercept-url pattern="/jsp/login.jsp" access="permitAll" />

    <logout logout-url="/j_spring_security_logout"
        invalidate-session="true" />

    <remember-me />

    <session-management invalid-session-url="/jsp/login.jsp?loggedout=true">
        <concurrency-control max-sessions="1"
            error-if-maximum-exceeded="false" />
    </session-management>

    <anonymous enabled='false'/>
</http>
```

What I know is, when the request comes for the application it will go in welcome-file-list for opening the jsp/login.jsp in my case, so it will directly open jsp/login.jsp page, but as we keep security, so it will go inside applicationContext-security.xml and check whether jsp/login.jsp needs to be filter or not and so on....then where does

```
<form-login login-page="/jsp/login.jsp" default-target-url="/jsp/index.jsp"
            authentication-failure-url="/jsp/login.jsp?login_error=1"
            always-use-default-target="true" />
```

will come in picture, also as per I know is it should go to "/jsp/login.jsp" page for login and if the credentials succes then it should go to /jsp/index.jsp, but it is opening /jsp/index.jsp page first....

can some one please guide me the correct flow.

thanks

Comment: You have no secured resources in your application, so a request for `index.jsp` will simply serve up the page.

Comment: But I have written like <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>  so all request will be transmitted to applicationContext-security.xml and where does welcome-file-list come in picture??

Comment: `welcome-file-list` has nothing to do with Spring Security. It's entirely a servlet container concept. It's not clear from your question why or how you're using it. If you want to be prompted for a login then you need to actually secure something using an `intercept-url` element which restricts access. I would rewrite your question with a clear definition of what the current request/response sequence is and what you actually want it to be. It's not very clear at the moment.